# How to prevent CORS issue when accessing window object in popup window?

Tags: oauth, discord, popupwindow, same-origin-policy

I am doing oauth authentication using discord api, I'm following this [blog](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-a-popup-for-oauth-login-38dee97f5f3b)

I'm able to get the auth code from the url but also I'm getting CORS issue

`SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame`.

Is there a way to prevent this?

The code:

```
    const CLIENT_URL = window.location.href;
    const popup = window.open(
      ` https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=*******&scope=identify&guilds.join&state=*******&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&prompt=consent
    `,
      "popup",
      "popup=true"
    );

    const checkPopup = setInterval(() => {
      if (popup.window.location.href.includes(CLIENT_URL)) {
        const params: any = new Proxy(
          new URLSearchParams(popup.window.location.search),
          {
            get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop),
          }
        );
        let value = params?.code;
        console.log(value);
        popup.close();
      }

      if (!popup || !popup.closed) return;
      clearInterval(checkPopup);
    }, 1000);
  };
```

Comment: This isn't a CORS issue (no cross-origin request is involved). Rather, what you're witnessing is one of the restrictions on cross-origin object access that the Same-Origin Policy enforces, and there's no generic way to disable it.

Comment: @jub0bs Is there any other way to resolve it?

Comment: What you can access cross-origin is pretty limited. Perhaps consider using the `postMessage` API.

Answer (score 0):

maybe add the **try/catch** in setInterval is available.

```js
const checkPopup = setInterval(() => {
   try {
      if (popup.window.location.href.includes(CLIENT_URL)) {
        const params: any = new Proxy(
          new URLSearchParams(popup.window.location.search),
          {
            get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop),
          }
        );
        let value = params?.code;
        console.log(value);
        popup.close();
      }

      if (!popup || !popup.closed) return;
      clearInterval(checkPopup);
    } catch (e) {
      // something
    }
}, 1000);
```